Question About Proof of Proposition 2.3.1 in Measure Theory by Donald Cohn
I am self-studying Donald Cohn's Measure Theory, and I got stuck on a step in his proof of Proposition 2.3.1. Here is the statement of the proposition as well as its proof until the point where I have trouble:

Proposition 2.3.1$\quad$ Let $\mathscr{S_+}$ be the collection of nonnegative simple real-valued $\mathscr{A}$-measurable functions on $X$. Let $(X,\mathscr{A},\mu)$ be a measure space, let $f$ and $g$ belong to $\mathscr{S_+}$, and let $\alpha$ be a nonnegative real number. Then
(a) $\int\alpha fd\mu = \alpha\int fd\mu$,
(b) $\int(f+g)d\mu = \int fd\mu + \int gd\mu$, and
(c) if $f(x)\leq g(x)$ holds at each $x$ in $X$, then $\int fd\mu\leq\int gd\mu$.


Proof$\quad$ Suppose that $f = \sum_{i=1}^ma_i\chi_{A_i}$, where $a_1,\dots,a_m$ are nonnegative real numbers and $A_1,\dots,A_m$ are disjoint subsets of $X$ that belong to $\mathscr{A}$, and that $g = \sum_{j=1}^nb_j\chi_{B_j}$, where $b_1,\dots,b_n$ are nonnegative real numbers and $B_1,\dots,B_n$ are disjoint subsets of $X$ that belong to $\mathscr{A}$. We can assume that $\bigcup_{i=1}^mA_i = \bigcup_{j=1}^nB_j$. ...

Why can we assume $\bigcup_{i=1}^mA_i = \bigcup_{j=1}^nB_j$? Do $f$ and $g$ have the same domain $X$? Is it true that $\bigcup_{i=1}^mA_i = \bigcup_{j=1}^nB_j = X$?
Thanks a lot for any help!

Note: The function $\chi_A$ is the characteristic function
\begin{align*}
\chi_A(x)=
\begin{cases}
1\ \text{if $x\in A$}\\
0\ \text{if $x\notin A$}.
\end{cases}
\end{align*}

Consider the special case $f=\chi_A$ and $g=\chi_B$.  Can you figure out a way to write f as a nonnegative linear combination of characteristic functions of measurable sets whose union is $A\cup B$?

@MatthewTowers Whenever necessary, multiply the characterictic function by $0$.

I think I figured out where I had problem. It would be better if the proof had been stated as follows: Suppose that $f = \sum_{i=1}^ma_i\chi_{A_i}$, where $a_1,\dots,a_m$ are nonnegative real numbers and $A_1,\dots,A_m$ are disjoint subsets of $X$ that belong to $\mathscr{A}$, and that $g = \sum_{j=1}^nb_j\chi_{B_j}$, where $b_1,\dots,b_n$ are nonnegative real numbers and $B_1,\dots,B_n$ are disjoint subsets of $X$ that belong to $\mathscr{A}$, and such that $\bigcup_{i=1}^mA_i = \bigcup_{j=1}^nB_j$.

Yes, both $f$ and $g$ have the same domain, $X$. It is given that $A_i \in \mathcal{A}.$ Then, for index $m+1$, set $A_{m+1}=(\cup_{i=1}^m A_i)^c.$ See that $A_{m+1} \in \mathcal{A}.$
For this index $m+1,$ set $a_{m+1}=0$ and this is perfectly valid since $0$ is non-negative real number.
Do the same thing for $B_i$'s.
Now, can you see why the proof works well.
